# How to pass ArrayList that contains Base64 String to another activity from recyclerview

Tags: android, base64

I am working on a project where i need to create Image Preview Functionality.For that i have created a recyclerview in which i am passing ArrayList of bitmap and displaying it in recyclerview.Now i am converting that arraylist into base64 string array and want to pass that arraylist into new activity using parcelable.
But i am getting TransactionTooLarge Execption.

Is there another way to pass the array to another activity?

Here is my adapter

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<UploadImageModel> mBitmapArray;
    private Context context;
    private UploadImageModel mUploadImageModel;
    private ArrayList<Base64ArrayModel> mBase64ArrayList;
    private Base64ArrayModel mBase64ArrayModel;

    public ImageListAdapter(ArrayList<UploadImageModel> mBitmapArray, ArrayList<Base64ArrayModel> mBase64ArrayList, Context context) {
        this.mBitmapArray = mBitmapArray; //Here i am getting arraylist that contains bitmaps
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_set, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mUploadImageModel = mBitmapArray.get(position);

        holder.UploadImageView.setImageBitmap(mUploadImageModel.getUploadImageBitmap());

        holder.UploadImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent openPreviewActivity = new Intent(context, PreviewActivity.class);
                openPreviewActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myImageList",encodeList());
                context.startActivity(openPreviewActivity);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBitmapArray.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView UploadImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            UploadImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.UploadImageView);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Base64ArrayModel> encodeList() {

        mBase64ArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mBitmapArray.size(); i++) {
            mBase64ArrayList.add(new Base64ArrayModel(ConstantFunction.encodeToBase64(mBitmapArray.get(i).getUploadImageBitmap(), Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100)));
        }
        return mBase64ArrayList;
    }
}
```

and the model i am using is as follows

```
public class Base64ArrayModel implements Parcelable {

    public String mBase64BitmapString;

    public String getmBase64BitmapString() {
        return mBase64BitmapString;
    }

    public void setmBase64BitmapString(String mBase64BitmapString) {
        this.mBase64BitmapString = mBase64BitmapString;
    }

    public Base64ArrayModel(String mBase64BitmapString)
    {
        this.mBase64BitmapString=mBase64BitmapString;
    }

    protected Base64ArrayModel(Parcel in) {
        mBase64BitmapString = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mBase64BitmapString);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Base64ArrayModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Base64ArrayModel>() {
        @Override
        public Base64ArrayModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Base64ArrayModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Base64ArrayModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Base64ArrayModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

How can i pass that arrayList to new activity?

Comment: try to get it as byte data. then i think ,it will be ok  then

Comment: Yes i tried but error remains the same

Comment: can we see the code how you have done.

Comment: Which Part? I have posted adapter where i am getting bitmap arraylist and now i want to convert it into arrayList which contains base64 strings

Comment: Base64 encryption will make string length long.Leave it . and try to pass it as byte. that's what i'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html),

> During a remote procedure call, the arguments and the return value of
>   the call are transferred as Parcel objects stored in the Binder
>   transaction buffer. If the arguments or the return value are too large
>   to fit in the transaction buffer, then the call will fail and
>   *TransactionTooLargeException* will be thrown.
>
> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently **1Mb**,
>   which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.
>   Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many
>   transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions
>   are of moderate size.

So, this basically means, you're trying to pass data with a size greater than the Binder Transaction Buffer can contain. To overcome this, you've to reduce the size of the data(base64String size, for your case). I can see you've this 
`ConstantFunction.encodeToBase64(mBitmapArray.get(i).getUploadImageBitmap(), Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100)` method for encoding a bitmap to base64String where you've passed 100 as compression level. In your implementation, if you use `bitmap.compress` method to compress the bitmap then try to reduce the number. The less the number the less quality it would get after the compression hence, you'll get small sized base64String in the end.

Comment: Then what should i do for achiving this task without loosing bitmap quality?

Comment: Showing image from server is the best way in terms of light weightiness. As for local storage, it's better to compress the bitmaps as much as you can sacrifice. Play around with the compression level and see where the image gets distorted. Then fix the compression level right above the distortion level.

Comment: Right now I have saved the arrayList in ConstantFunction Class and retriving it in next activity and its working fine.But i guess this is not the good way

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus :

1. Create event and then post the arraylist and receive wherever you want to..

for E.g

```
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

//create class
    public class Base64Event {
        public final List< Base64ArrayModel > base64Array;
        public Base64Event(List< Base64ArrayModel > base64Array){

    }
    }
```

//Post

```
  EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new Base64Event(base64Array));
```

//Reciever in activity

```
  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void anyName(Base64Event event) {
      event. base64Array //here is the data passed
    }
```

Comment: it will pass the array list from one activity to other activities

Comment: where ever the event is being listened, the data will be revived

Answer (score 0):

first, you add this line into your manifest file.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Because simultaneously at a time your transaction too large. So make one singleton class like. It is not preferred way I want to suggest use database but if you have not any other choice than this one is better for you.

```
public class DataTransactionModel {

    private static volatile DataTransactionModel instance = null;
    private ArrayList<Base64ArrayModel> list = null;

    private DataTransactionModel() {
    }

    public static synchronized DataTransactionModel getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DataTransactionModel.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DataTransactionModel();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Bitmap getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = list;
    }
}
```

Set data into this singleton class and then after get list of images with the help of singleton class methods.

```
    ...

    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            mUploadImageModel = mBitmapArray.get(position);

            holder.UploadImageView.setImageBitmap(mUploadImageModel.getUploadImageBitmap());

            holder.UploadImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DataTransactionModel model = DataTransactionModel.getInstance();
                    model.setList(encodeList());
                    Intent openPreviewActivity = new Intent(context, PreviewActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(openPreviewActivity);

                }
            });
        }
```